# Flex and Bison ignore function body

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

Hi I'm trying to make simple C compiler using flex and bison to check that every declared function was implemented. My problem is that i want to skip everything what is in function body.
Example

```
int main()
{
    int n, flag;

    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Check prime number
    flag = checkPrimeNumber(n);
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("%d is a prime number.\n", n);
    else
        printf("%d is not a prime number.\n", n);

    // Check Armstrong number
    flag = checkArmstrongNumber(n);
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("%d is an Armstrong number.", n);
    else
        printf("%d is not an Armstrong number.",n);
    return 0;
}
```

everything beetween "{" and "}". But inside function we can have if(){} and while etc.

How to prevent this situation

now my lex file

```
%{
#include "compilator_p.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

void yyerror(const char *);

%}

alpha [a-zA-Z_] 
digit [0-9]

%%

[\t]        ;
[\n] { yylineno = yylineno + 1;}

int return INT;
float return FLOAT;
char return CHAR;
void return VOID;
"{".*"}" return BODY;

^"#include ".+ ;

[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]       { /* DO NOTHING */ }

";" return yytext[0];
"(" return yytext[0];
")" return yytext[0];
"," return yytext[0];

%%
```

Comment: Can't you just copy the `[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^*/][^*]*[*]+)*[/]       { /* DO NOTHING */ }` and change the regex to match `{...}`? If you actually want flex to parse the contents of the function, you should do this in your bison file

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to write the parser from scratch for a school assignment I suggest that you use an existing grammar (such as https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-y.html) and simply leave most of the actions empty.